# How can I compile unix program and its dependencies into one single executable on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, unix, compilation, terminal

After I typing `brew install pianobar` from Terminal to install pianobar, I can run it from my Terminal perfectly.

I go to `/usr/local/Cellar/pianobar/2011.11.11/bin` and copy the pianobar executable to my Desktop. It works too when I double click on it.

Then I make a copy to my another non-development Mac (no Xcode installed) and try to execute it, it says `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libao.4.dylib`.

I do know that pianobar has such dependencies:

```
depends_on 'libao'
depends_on 'mad'
depends_on 'faad2'
depends_on 'gnutls'
```

These dependencies are dynamically linked to the executable on my first Mac, so pianobar can't work on another if these dependencies haven't installed.

My question is: how can I compile all these dependencies into one executable so I can distribute it to my another Mac easily?

Comment: Well, you *statically* link them. Where are you getting stuck on that?

Comment: Yes! to @dmckee 's comment. Hover your mouse over each tag and see the # of followers. You will get more 'eye's on your problem if you use a tag like make or gmake (Is there a special make program for osx?). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple, but probably too complicated ways to achieve that, like:

- create a MacOS X Installer Package (using PackageMaker.app) and ensure all libs are in there too
- build everything manually and distribute as ZIP

A lot easier is to just install homebrew on the second Mac and install pianobar there too.

Comment: Thanks. These are the options. But like I said, I want to compile all these dependencies into one *FAT* executable? (fatter than the dynamic linking executable). The result should be an executable not an .app, Zip or something else.